# SQL corner case problem using find_in_set and group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

The following SQL code is for score ranking output.

```
SELECT Score, 
        FIND_IN_SET(Score,
                    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                        DISTINCT Score ORDER BY Score DESC
                    ) 
                    FROM Scores)) AS Rank 
                    FROM Scores 
        ORDER BY Rank ASC;
```

However, I find that this piece of code works usually but falls for some case such as for the table like

[image: enter link description here]

Any idea why this code would not work in the case above ?

Comment: tag your dbms name

Comment: Please include sample data in the question.  Yours is a great example of a link not working, so the question makes no sense.